# Rails is escaping my query incorrectly

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am trying to handle a fairly complex query within active record. I am using rails 4.0 and mysql. The problem is, my query requires single quotes in the WHERE statement.

This is what the sql statement (WHERE portion) needs to end up looking like:

```
WHERE 
   `location_hours`.`open_at` <=
     hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'US/Mountain',`locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60 
AND 
   `location_hours`.`close_at` >= 
     hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'US/Mountain', `locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60
```

The issue is with 'US/Mountain'.  I have tried the following two ways to make this work:

**1.**

```
string = "hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'US/Mountain', `locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60";
filtered = filtered.joins(:hours)
  .where("`location_hours`.`closed` = ?", false)
  .where("`location_hours`.`open_at` <= %s AND `location_hours`.`close_at` >= %s",
    string, string)
```

**2.**

```
filtered = filtered.joins(:hours)
      .where("`location_hours`.`day` = weekday(CONVERT_TZ(now(), \"US/Mountain\", `locations`.`time_zone`))")
      .where("`location_hours`.`closed` = ?", false)
      .where("`location_hours`.`open_at` <= hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), \"US/Mountain\", `locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60 AND `location_hours`.`close_at` >= hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), \"US/Mountain\", `locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60")
```

The sql the second option generates (copy,pasted from console) I can literally drop as a raw query into phpmyadmin, and I get results back.

For some reason Rails is doing something funny with my query.  Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: why those *backticks* you used like ? I am not gettiing it

Comment: @ArupRakshit MySQL uses backticks to quote identifiers (table names, column names, ...) in its version of SQL. Standard SQL uses double quotes for that purpose. SQL Server uses brackets. They're only needed if the identifiers contain whitespace characters, are keywords, ...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get single quotes into your SQL is to just put them in there:

```
.where("location_hours.open_at <= hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'US/Mountain', ...
```

If the timezone is in a variable then use a placeholder:

```
.where("location_hours.open_at <= hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), :tz, ...", :tz => time_zone_string)
```

Keep in mind that an SQL snippet such as

```
string = "hour(CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'US/Mountain', `locations`.`time_zone`)) * 60 * 60";
```

is not an SQL string and should not be escaped as such. That means that sending it through a `%s` won't do the right thing, the `%s` will just make a mess of the quotes in the snippet.

BTW, you don't need to backtick-quote everything, only identifiers that are keywords, case sensitive, contain whitespace, etc. Backticking everything just makes an ugly mess.